# Standard ML style: is variable shadowing good style?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

in standard ML, is variable shadowing in general, and in particular, when pattern matching acceptable? For this toy example:

```
  case xs of
      [] => 0
    | x::xs => x + sum xs
```

Is the following better style?

```
fun sum(xs) =
  case xs of
      [] => 0
    | x::xs' => x + sum xs'
```

Without shadowing, one has to pick different names, which clutters the code, especially when nested patterns, `let` function bindings, and other language constructs are being used.
Thank you!

Comment: It's common to structure the code so it doesn't use nested patterns and complex let constructions if it gets unwieldy, but I think most would pick `y::ys` over either of your suggestions.

Comment: I think this question has a clear answer — no, it's not good style. However, solutions to this are rather subjective and often chosen on a case by case basis. Also, in the grand scheme of things, there are more important things in a codebase than a few shadowed variables or maybe some `'`-suffixed ones (if they're used in small functions with clear cut responsibilities, I can accept the bad variable naming).

Comment: well personally I like it, it makes it impossible to make an error by referring to the shadowed variable when it is no longer valid to do so. I also like it because it lets me avoid the primed names which I find immensely confusing. (I'm no MLer though)

Answer (score 1):

> is variable shadowing good style?

No.

But also `xs` and `xs'` aren't good either: They have the same type so it is very easy to accidentally use one instead of the other. In your case this probably leads to infinite recursion and that gets detected soon enough. But in other cases it might lead to more subtle bugs. This advice is not particular to functional programming.

***Edit:** For totality I'm including molbdnilo's suggestion of `y::ys`:*

```
fun sum xs =
    case xs of
         [] => 0
       | y::ys => y + sum ys
```

An alternative is to only pattern match and bind the values you actually need. In your `sum` example you don't actually need the full input for anything other than splitting apart. So you might write it like

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
```

Or with even more implicit pattern matching matching:

```
val sum = foldl op+ 0
```

Another  example, [Exercism's Bob exercise](https://github.com/exercism/sml/tree/master/exercises/bob), can be solved by first sanitizing the input and then classifying it:

```
datatype diction = Yelling | Asking | YellingAsking | Whatever

fun strip message = ...

fun classify message = ...

fun answer diction = ...

val response = answer o classify o strip
```

Here the `message` of the function `strip` will contain unstripped whitespace and the `message` of the `classify` function won't. So instead of having multiple `message`s, one having whitespace and the other one not, you put them in separate scopes of functions that do separate things.

Comment: The suggestion `y::ys` is great for generic code but when code is using specific names such as `card`, `grade`, etc, then substituting the names becomes a challenge, and most likely, we have to use names such as `card'` and `grade'`.

Comment: Yes, so what `y::ys` does in favor is that it visually looks completely different from `xs`. A similar thing you can do for domain-specific value bindings like `card` is to name it like `cardHand`, `gradeBefore` or whatever clarifies the context: You won't get the wrong variable as easily, if they coexist in the same namespace, and reading a misuse might trigger a "hey, that's wrong."